# Functor that maps to both $KO^n$ and $KO^{-n}$

Tags: kt.k-theory-and-homology, at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

(my question is also meaningful for complex *K*-theory, but since *K*<sup>*n*</sup>(X) is always isomorphic to *K*<sup>-*n*</sup>(*X*), it's less interesting)

---

I start by recalling the analytic definition of *KO*-theory:

The following ingredients are needed:

**Clifford algebras:**
For *n*∈ℤ, the Clifford algebra *Cliff*(*n*) is the following ℤ/2-graded *C**-algebra:
• $\langle e_1,\ldots, e_n\;|\; e_i \text{ is odd}, e_i^2=1, e_ie_j=-e_je_i, e_i^*=e_i\rangle$ if *n* ≥ 0.
• $\langle e_1,\ldots, e_{-n}\;|\; e_i \text{ is odd}, e_i^2=-1, e_ie_j=-e_je_i, e_i^*=-e_i\rangle$ if *n* ≤ 0.
*Note:* The above definition might seem a bit weird with its two cases *n* ≥ 0 and *n* ≤ 0, but actually it's quite ok: the map *n* $\mapsto$ *Cliff*(*n*) can be extended to a homomorphism from the associative group (ℤ,+) to the monoidal 2-category of ℤ/2-graded *C*${}^*$-algebras, bimodules, and bimodule maps.

**Fredholm operators:**
If *H* is a Hilbert space, then
an operator *F* : *H*→ *H* is called Fredholm if boths its kernel and cokernel are finite dimensional.

> ### *The definition:*
>
> Let *X* be a topological space. A class in *KO<sup>n</sup>*(*X*) is represented by:
>
> **Option *#1*:**
>   • A bundle of ℤ/2-graded real Hilbert spaces over *X*.
>   • Actions of *Cliff*(*n*) on the fibers of the above bundle.
>   • Fiberwise Fredholm operators that are odd, *Cliff*-linear, and skew-adjoint.
>   **Option *#2*:**
>   • A bundle of ℤ/2-graded real Hilbert spaces over *X*.
>   • Actions of *Cliff*(*-n*) on the fibers of the above bundle.
>   • Fiberwise Fredholm operators that are odd, *Cliff*-linear, and self-adjoint.

Dually, a class in *KO<sup>-n</sup>*(*X*) can be represented by:

> **Option *#1*:**
>   • A bundle of ℤ/2-graded real Hilbert spaces over *X*.
>   • Actions of *Cliff*(*n*) on the fibers of the above bundle.
>   • Fiberwise Fredholm operators that are odd, *Cliff*-linear, and self-adjoint.
>   **Option *#2*:**
>   • A bundle of ℤ/2-graded real Hilbert spaces over *X*.
>   • Actions of *Cliff*(*-n*) on the fibers of the above bundle.
>   • Fiberwise Fredholm operators that are odd, *Cliff*-linear, and skew-adjoint.

---

If the bundles are finite dimensional, then the Fredholm operators can be taken to be zero.
As a consequence, we get two maps

- Bundles of finite dimensional *Cliff*(*n*)-modules over *X*${}\to KO^n(X)$
- Bundles of finite dimensional *Cliff*(*n*)-modules over *X*${}\to KO^{-n}(X)$

In other words, a bundle of finite dimensional *Cliff*(*n*)-modules represents *both* an element in *KO<sup>n</sup>*(*X*) and in *KO<sup>-n</sup>*(*X*)*!*

> *Is there a homotopy-theoretical explanation of the above phenomenon?
>
>   Are there other cohomology theories *E* that have functors mapping to both
>   *E<sup>n</sup>*(*X*) and *E<sup>-n</sup>*(*X*)?
>
>   Maybe for *E=TMF*?*

Comment: This question captures much of what I've never understood about Bott periodicity.  I think of it this way: you have maps $f:K(Cliff(n))\rightleftarrows K(Cliff(n+1)): g$, where $f$ comes from tensoring up along a ring homomorphism $Cliff(n)\to Cliff(n+1)$, and $g$ from restricting along the same homomorphism. The fibers of the $f$'s give you the spaces in the $KO$-spectrum; the fibers of the $g$'s give you the same spaces *in the opposite order*!  Weird.

Comment: Am I correct that in the definition of $\operatorname{Cliff}(-n)$, you mean for the sequence to start at $e_{-1}$?

Comment: Also, I don't really understand the difference between $\operatorname{Cliff}(n)$ and $\operatorname{Cliff}(-n)$.  If I multiply all generators by $\sqrt{-1}$, don't I switch $n \leftrightarrow -n$?

Comment: @Theo: The algebras under consideration are real, not complex.

Comment: Maybe Kasparov theory helps to tidy the confusion a bit. Option #2 (in the first grey box) amounts to an element in $KK(R; C(X) 
\otimes Cl (-n))$, while option #1 (also in the first box) amounts to an element in $KK(Cl(n);C(X))$. 
To get this from option #1, multiply the Fredholm with the grading involution and obtain a self-adjoint one that anticommutes with
 $Cl(n)$. Both groups are isomorphic (by ''abstract Bott periodicity'').

Comment: @Theo: In the definition of Cliff(n) for negative $n$, the sequence of generators starts at $e_1$, and goes until $e_{-n}$ (recall that -n is positive).

Comment: Well, yes, it's nifty that K-theory has an explicit presentation (or two) that is symmetric at the level of chain groups; but homology isn't about chain groups, is it?

Comment: What do you mean? I totally disagree. Homology is exactly all about chain groups (or, more accurately, cohomology is all about cocycle groups). You can recover the equivalence on $Z^n(X)$ by looking at $Z^n(X\times [0,1])$.